Unknown file extension ".css" for /node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/theme/classiceditor.css
I am trying to integrate CKEditor 5 into my Remix project with custom build, but I am encountering an error related to a file that I have not included in my project folder. I am using Tailwind CSS and TypeScript with Remix-Run.
How can I resolve this issue? Is anyone else facing this problem, or can anyone share code snippets for integrating CKEditor 5 with a Remix project?
Here is my custom build code:
import ClassicEditorBase from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor";
import Essentials from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials";
import Bold from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold";
import Italic from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic";
import Heading from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading/src/heading";
import Link from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/link";
import Table from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/table";
import TableToolbar from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/tabletoolbar";
import List from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/src/list";

class CustomEditor extends ClassicEditorBase {}

CustomEditor.builtinPlugins = [
  Essentials,
  Bold,
  Italic,
  Heading,
  Link,
  Table,
  TableToolbar,
  List,
];

CustomEditor.defaultConfig = {
  toolbar: {
    items: [
      "heading",
      "bold",
      "italic",
      "link",
      "bulletedList",
      "numberedList",
      "insertTable",
      "undo",
      "redo",
    ],
  },
  language: "en",
};

export default CustomEditor;

Route file:
import { useState } from "react";
import { TextEditor } from "~/components/TextEditor"; 

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [editorData, setEditorData] = useState<string>("");

  const handleEditorChange = (event: any, editor: any) => {
    const data = editor.getData();
    setEditorData(data);
    console.log({ event, data });
  };

  return (
    <div className="editor-wrapper p-4 border-2 border-gray-300 rounded-lg">
      <h1>Custom CKEditor</h1>
      <TextEditor data={editorData} onChange={handleEditorChange} />
      <h2 className="font-semibold px-7">Output:</h2>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: editorData }} />
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;

Texteditor file:
import { CKEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import CustomEditor from "~/modules/editor/ckeditor"; 
interface TextEditorProps {
  data: string;
  onChange: (event: any, editor: any) => void; // Use 'any' for simplicity
}

export function TextEditor({ data, onChange }: TextEditorProps) {
  return (
    <CKEditor
      editor={CustomEditor} // Use the custom editor build
      data={data}
      onChange={onChange}
      onReady={(editor) => {
        console.log("Editor is ready!", editor);
      }}
      onBlur={(event, editor) => {
        console.log("Editor blur.", editor);
      }}
      onFocus={(event, editor) => {
        console.log("Editor focus.", editor);
      }}
    />
  );
}

